# An basic question of linear algebra and the vectorial spaces.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm studying Differencial Geometry for a exam and I'm having some trouble to do this. In this course we viewed dual spaces, forms, Gauss Bonnet Theorem... Hm.. this is it!

> Let $V$ a vectorial space, $\dim(V)=n$ and $T:V \rightarrow V$ an linear aplication. The *trace* of $T$ is the number $tr(T)$ such that: 
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n\Delta(v_1,...,v_{i-1},T(v_i),...,v_n)=tr(T)\Delta(v_1,...,v_n)
> $$
>   where $\Delta \in \bigwedge^n(V^*)$ 
>   If $(e^1,...,e^n)$ is a base of $V$ and $T(e_i)=\sum a_i^je_j$ show that
>
> $$
> tr(T)=\sum a_i^i
> $$

I have not idea how to do this, can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand this symbol $î$ you've written. What does it mean?

Comment: @ Felipe:  I share Muphrid's curiosity.  Perhaps by $\hat i$ you mean $e^i$?  That would make sense to me . . .

Comment: @Muphrid
Was a typo! I corrected.

Comment: @RobertLewis Was a typo! I corrected.

Comment: @ Felipe:  OK, got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the basis vectors $e_i$ in place of the vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ in the definition of the trace.  Because $\Delta$ is an $n$-form, it is alternating.  Any term of the form $\Delta(\ldots, e_j, \ldots, a_i^j e_j, \ldots)$ must evaluate to zero.

For this reason, the only terms that contribute are those of the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta(e_1, e_2, \ldots, T(e_i), \ldots) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta(e_1, e_2, \ldots, a^i_i e_i, \ldots)$$

I think you should be able to take it from here?

Comment: I follow this idea but, I got $$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^i e_i= tr(T)(e_i)$$ working at each coordinate, this is ok? I'm insecurity with  this last part equating each coordinate.

Comment: The answer you get should be a number (a scalar) not a vector.  All the vectors $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$ should be annihilated by the $n$-form $\Delta$.

Comment: Why I can affirm that $$ \sum_{i=1}^na^i_i=tr(T)\Delta(e_1,...,e_n) \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^na^i_i=tr(T)?$$
I'm conffused!

Comment: You're not being asked to do that, and I didn't write any such thing.  You should end up with $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^i \Delta(e_1, \ldots, e_n) = \mathrm{Tr}(T) \Delta (e_1, \ldots, e_n)$.

Comment: Sorry for that! Now I got it! Thank you very much! I forgot that $\Delta(e_1,...,ke_i,...,e_n)=k\Delta(e_1,...,e_i,...,e_n)$ and this killed me!